# Integral representation of a quotient of odd and even parabolic cylinder functions

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

In some work on nonlinear splines in space, the following expression arises:
$$\frac{e^{-\mathrm{i}\pi/4} \; y_2 \left( \frac{\mathrm{i}}{4 \alpha} -\frac{1}{2} ; e^{\mathrm{i}\pi/4} \sqrt{\alpha} s \right)}{2 \sqrt{\alpha} \;\;\; \, y_1  \left( \frac{\mathrm{i}}{4 \alpha} -\frac{1}{2} ; e^{\mathrm{i}\pi/4} \sqrt{\alpha} s \right) } = \frac{s \,_1F_1\left(\frac{\mathrm{i}}{8 \, \alpha} + \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2} ; \frac{\mathrm{i} \, \alpha s^{2}}{2} \right)}{2 \,_1F_1\left( \frac{\mathrm{i}}{8 \, \alpha} , \frac{1}{2}  ; \frac{\mathrm{i} \, \alpha s^{2}}{2} \right)}    
    $$
$y_1(a;z)$ and $y_2(a;z)$ are the even and odd parabolic cylinder functions and on the RHS, we have a form using confluent hypergeometric functions.  $a$ and $s$ are real and positive.

This expression is a parametrization of the stereographic projection of the spherical clothoid onto the complex plane.

I am looking for a simple integral representation of this expression. Shown below is a plot of the spherical clothoid and its stereographic projection for $\alpha=1$ and $s \in [0,5]$:

[image: Plot of the spherical clothoid and its stereographic projection]